# Django - Autocomplete_Light's "Add Another" popup declares: "'initial' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I am working on getting the "add another" popup to work with `django-autocomplete_light`.

Following along in the docs:

http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/addanother.html

I have set up my URLs:

```
import autocomplete_light.shortcuts as al

from AlmondKing.FinancialLogs import models
from AlmondKing.FinancialLogs import forms

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^branches/autocreate/$', al.CreateView.as_view(
        model=models.CompanyBranch, form_class=forms.CompanyBranch),
        name='branch_autocreate'),
]
```

and my autocomplete_light_registry.py

```
al.register(CompanyBranch,
    search_fields=['^branch_name'],
    attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Branch',
        'data-autocomplete-minimum-characters': 1,
    },
    widget_attrs={
        'data-widget-maximum-values': 1,
        'class': 'modern-style',
    },
    add_another_url_name='company:branch_autocreate',
)
```

However, when I click the plus sign to add a new related object, I get the following error:

> TypeError at /company/branches/autocreate/
>
> 'initial' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

I've been trying to find a way to do this for a while and I'm so close!

Now, I am hoping someone can read the traceback and help me understand what went wrong:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/company/branches/autocreate/?_popup=1&winName=id_branch

Django Version: 1.8.2
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'AlmondKing.InventoryLogs',
 'AlmondKing.FinancialLogs',
 'AlmondKing.AKGenius',
 'autocomplete_light')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'AlmondKing.AKGenius.middleware.RequireLoginMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Adam\Envs\AlmondKing\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adam\Envs\AlmondKing\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adam\Envs\AlmondKing\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adam\Envs\AlmondKing\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  245.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adam\Envs\AlmondKing\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  205.         form = self.get_form()
File "C:\Users\Adam\Envs\AlmondKing\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_form
  74.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
File "C:\Users\Adam\Envs\AlmondKing\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __init__
  480.                 raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])

Exception Type: TypeError at /company/branches/autocreate/
Exception Value: 'initial' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    add_another_url_name='company:branch_autocreate',

    add_another_url_name='branch_autocreate',
```